# how save data to excel manually

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpexcel

How do i make my code make it manually save in excel? because so far in my code it will transfer my filtered data from mysql database to Excel file...how can i make it manual save without making a excel file in my program folder in order to generate excel report in my data.

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';
$filename = 'file.xlsx';
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cant connect!");
mysql_select_db("test") or die ("cant find database!");

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score");
if(isset($_POST['send'])){

$headings = array(
    'ID', 
    'NAME',
    'SCORE 1',
    'SCORE 2',
    'OTHER QUALITIES',
    'INTERVIEW',
    'TOTAL',
    'AIC',
    'BATCHCODE',
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($headings, null, 'A1');
$row = 2;
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, null, 'A' . $row);
   $row++;
}
echo 'saved';
header('Location: Index.php');
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($filename);
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send to excel" id="send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do is if I click send to excel(button)...an excel save dialog will pop-up in order to save my filtered data to excel.

Comment: Eliminate all echoed or printed characters from the script or non-php blocks (such as your `<html><head>....` markup tags, etc); send appropriate headers to tell browser to expect an Excel format file, save file to `php://output`.... exactly as demonstrated in `Examples/01simple-download-xls.php` in the PHPExcel distribution

Comment: @Mark Baker can u edit my code...im just a newbie programmer...i tried the example but it automaticaly download the file...i want is if i click the button a excel save dialog will pop-up so that i can manually change the file name....do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['send']) { ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php } else {
    require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';
    $filename = 'file.xlsx';
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cant connect!");
    mysql_select_db("test") or die ("cant find database!");

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score");
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){

        $headings = array(
            'ID', 
            'NAME',
            'SCORE 1',
            'SCORE 2',
            'OTHER QUALITIES',
            'INTERVIEW',
            'TOTAL',
            'AIC',
            'BATCHCODE',
        );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($headings, null, 'A1');
        $row = 2;
        while( $rows = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, null, 'A' . $row);
            $row++;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
if (!isset($_POST['send']) { ?>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send to excel" id="send" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 2....got errors